# Python :TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: python, class, email, arguments

When the user enters an email address, and the program reads the email and display it according to its criteria (e.g `yeo.myy@edu.co`), like criteria:

- `username` is `yeo.myy`
- `domain` is `edu.co`

I know its something to do  with the `"@"`.

this is the code

```
class Email:
    def __int__(self,emailAddr):
        self.emailAddr = emailAddr


    def domain(self):
        index = 0
        for i in range(len(emailAddr)):
            if emailAddr[i] == "@":
                index = i
            return self.emailAddr[index+1:]

    def username(self):
        index = 0
        for i in range(len(emailAddr)):
            if emailAddr[i] == "@" :
                index = i
            return self.emailAddr[:index]

def main():

    emailAddr = raw_input("Enter your email>>")

    user = Email(emailAddr)

    print "Username = ", user.username()
    print "Domain = ", user.domain()

main()
```

this is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/sdsd", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/sdsd", line 24, in main
    user = Email(emailAddr)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Comment: seems that you have a typo in your definition of `init` function! try to change `int` to `init`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def __int__(self,emailAddr):
```

Did you mean `__init__`?

```
def __init__(self,emailAddr):
```

---

You're also missing a couple `self`s in your methods, and your `return`s are improperly indented.

```
def domain(self):
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(self.emailAddr)):
        if self.emailAddr[i] == "@":
            index = i
            return self.emailAddr[index+1:]

def username(self):
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(self.emailAddr)):
        if self.emailAddr[i] == "@" :
            index = i
            return self.emailAddr[:index]
```

Result:

```
Username =  yeo.myy
Domain =  edu.co
```

Incidentally, I recommend [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition) and [`rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.rpartition) for splitting a string into two pieces on a given separator. Sure beats keeping track of indices manually.

```
def domain(self):
    return self.emailAddr.rpartition("@")[2]
def username(self):
    return self.emailAddr.rpartition("@")[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing the same, instead of __init__, I was trying to use __int__.

Answer (score 1):

This error may happen if you type `def _init_`  with a single underline instead of `def __init__` with double underlines before and after init.

Answer (score -1):

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,Name,Age,Salary,Gender):
         self.Name = Name
         self.Age = Age
         self.Salary= Salary
         self.Gender = Gender
         
    def show_employee_deatils(self):
         print("Name of the employee is ",self.Name)
         print("Age of the employee is ",self.age)
         print("Salary of the employee is ",self.salary)
         print("gender of the employee is ",self.gender)
e1 = Employee('Shubham',25,25000,'male')
e1. show_Employee_deatils( )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.